# Failed to deploy Spring Boot application to WildFly

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

When I tried to deploy a Spring Boot application, in war packaging, to WildFly, errors came up as:

```
21:20:58,211 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 24) Application run failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'undertowServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedUndertow.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "MAX_HEADER_SIZE" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the referring class, io/undertow/UndertowOptions, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for the field's resolved type, org/xnio/Option, have different Class objects for that type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "MAX_HEADER_SIZE" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the referring class, io/undertow/UndertowOptions, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for the field's resolved type, org/xnio/Option, have different Class objects for that type
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.customize(UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.customize(UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessBeforeInitialization$0(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.lambda$null$0(LambdaSafe.java:287)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$LambdaSafeCallback.invoke(LambdaSafe.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.lambda$invoke$1(LambdaSafe.java:286)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.invoke(LambdaSafe.java:286)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    ... 38 more
```

I studies some similar reported issues, and set the spring-boot-starter-undertow to provided. HOwvwer, I still got errors. Here are pom contents:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <!-- exclude spring default logging to add log4j 2 -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WildFly ejb client support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
            <version>19.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I also tried to set wildfly-ejb-client-bom to provided, errors were still there. Please kindly advise. The WildFly is 19.1.0.

Comment: Can you add the code base for testing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong [BOM](https://github.com/wildfly/boms#usage) usage.

It should be used in `dependencyManagement`:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>19.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```